# Java Enterprise web development in netbeans

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, registration, netbeans-7

I am trying to build a simple form with mysql spring hibernate framework but it is giving errors.I cant figure out why model.hibernateUtil is not initialized. please help me.
Here is code for hibernateUtil :-

```
package model;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
public class HibernateUtil
{
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static
    {
       try
       {
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
       } 
       catch (Throwable ex)
       {    
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." +     ex);         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
       }
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

and this is the code for the controller

```
package controller;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import model.HibernateUtil;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;
public class UserController implements Controller
{
@Override
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse hsr1) throws Exception 
{
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("user");
    String out = "All User Details: ";
    try
    {
        Session session HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List result = session.createQuery("from Users").list();
        mv.addObject("users", result);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mv.addObject("message", out);
    return mv;
    }
}
```

These are the exceptions/errors that are coming.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class model.HibernateUtil
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1284)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

and

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class model.HibernateUtil
controller.UserController.handleRequest(UserController.java:18)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Please help me I am just a rookie. The database connectivity and all required drivers are in perfect working order.

The name of my database is User and it has 3 attributes by the names UserID, UserName, Password.

Comment: Can you change this statement `Session session HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();` in `UserController` class to 
`Session session = new HibernateUtil().getSessionFactory().openSession();`

Comment: On doing as you say it is giving error that the compiler can't find the symbol getSessionFactory in HibernateUtil